# Compare cells without register vba

Tags: vba

I have 2 cells

Cells(1,1) contains: ABC

Cells(1,2) contains: Abc_AR

Cells have different length. I need to vba compare the first three letter of these two cells without register. 
I tried to write smth like, but it doesn't work.

```
Sub faaa()
       Dim TestComp As Integer
       TestComp = StrComp(Left(Cells(1, 1),3), Left(Cells(1, 2),3) CompareMethod.Text)
       If TestComp = 0 Then MsgBox ("Equal!")

 End Sub
```

Comment: Add the following at the start of the code `Option Compare Text`. See [VBA - Excel : get rid of the case sensitivity when comparing words?](//stackoverflow.com/a/17035766)

Comment: Change `CompareMethod.Text` to `, vbTextCompare`

Comment: It is unclear if "doesn't work" means "doesn't do what I want" or "gives me an error." If that is the actual code, then you forgot to include a comma before `CompareMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
Sub AreTheyCloseEnough()
    If UCase(Left(Cells(1, 1).Value, 3)) = UCase(Left(Cells(1, 2).Value, 3)) Then
        MsgBox "pretty close"
    Else
        MsgBox "not close"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is fantastic solution as well!

Comment: @Andre  I tried to make the code easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Sub faaa()
   Dim TestComp As Integer
   TestComp = StrComp(UCase(Left(Cells(1, 1), 3)), UCase(Left(Cells(1, 2), 3)), vbTextCompare)
   If TestComp = 0 Then MsgBox ("Equal!")
End Sub
```